# What is the best way to organize your css code with comments?

Tags: html, css

CSS pros what do you guys think of this? If you guys don't think it's a good way to organize CSS code please let me know what the best way to organize CSS code is.

```css
/******* HEADER STYLES  *********/








/********* MAIN SECTION STYLES  ***********/













/********** FOOTER  ***************/











/*********** MEDIA QUERIES  **********/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a highly subjective topic, but I'm happy to weigh in. Everyone develops his/her own style for organizing code, and most are surprisingly territorial *(this answer will likely be downvoted by those who merely* ***disagree*** *with my preferences... _sigh_)*

At any rate, while most people prefer the standard style of:

```
#someID{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
#nutherID{
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

I prefer to pack the most information into the least space possible. To my view, why scroll six screens to see the same amount of information that I typically see on one screen. *Maybe it comes from doing most of my work on a laptop...*

```
#someID{width:200px;height:50px;border:1px solid red;}
#nutherID{text-align:center;color:blue;}
```

I organize my CSS into sections, as you do, but I also divide up my pages into divs/sections/whatever. I want to be able to quickly find the section of css that I need. So my labels, as you showed above, would be the section descriptions (e.g. `***** About *****`, `***** Some other section description *****`, etc)  Same idea as yourself, but more broken down.

I also have a bevy of standard css classes that I use for all projects, and I stick these at the top of the css file, such as:

```
***** GLOBAL *****
*{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;} /* Here come the down-votes... */
.bgBlack{background:black;}
.bgWheat{background:wheat;}
.taCenter{text-align:center;}
.taRight{text-align:right;}
```

Finally, I like to use indents to show nesting:

```
.about-outer{width:100%;height:500px;}
    .about-inner{border:1px solid #ccc;}
        .about-inner p{font-size:1.3rem;}
```

My $0.02...

Comment: To those upvoting this answer, please upvote the question also - it's a fair question, don't you think?